# Explain meaning and usages of 썰렁 - 썰렁해 and/or 썰렁썰렁

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, examples

### Explain meaning and usages of 썰렁 - 썰렁해 and/or 썰렁썰렁

To be clear, I have heard it used in each of these ways.  I do not need an explanation of Noun, Noun+하다 (Noun+해), but if any usage carries a different meaning, please indicate the nuance.

I should say, that I understand it to be a comment about one's humor and perhaps also to have something to do with the cold.  Perhaps it is a play on words.

I'm also interested in any negativity that this might convey in each particular usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[썰렁](http://krdic.naver.com/seo.nhn?id=24382401) is literally meant for climate or weatherly situation. 썰렁 is describing  slight windy and cold weather. It also can be used in horrific scene from movie, books or story. 
However, it mostly describes a humor rather not funny because it is old , malformed humor or missed punch line mostly.

For example, 
야 그 썰렁한 얘기 이제는 그만 좀 해.
진우는 맨날 썰렁한 얘기만 해 (contextually either not funny or horror story)